# React Native: how to change status bar icon colors

Tags: ios, ios9, react-native

I can't seem to find a way to change the colors of the status bar icons to white - at the top of the screen, e.g time & battery.

[image: iPhone 6 screenshot]

I've tried adding the following in info.plist

- Status bar style: UIStatusBarStyleLightContent
- View controller-based status bar appearance: NO

But only seems to work in previous versions of IOS. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 41):

You need to use `StatusBarIOS` inside your React Native component:

`StatusBarIOS.setStyle('light-content')`

Docs here: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbarios.html#content

**Edit: As of RN 0.22**, `StatusBarIOS` has been deprecated and the cross-platform `StatusBar` should be used. It has still be used imperatively as is mentioned above:

`StatusBar.setBarStyle('light-content', true);`

However, the recommended way to use this component is declaratively. For example:

```
 <View>
   <StatusBar
     backgroundColor="blue"
     barStyle="light-content"
   />
   <Navigator
     initialRoute={{statusBarHidden: true}}
     renderScene={(route, navigator) =>
       <View>
         <StatusBar hidden={route.statusBarHidden} />
         ...
       </View>
     }
   />
 </View>
```

See the new docs here: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbar.html

Comment: any idea on how to set it on `componentDidMount`/`componentWillMount`? I tried it but it seems to work only from a callback to a user action (i.e. onPress on a Touchable)

Comment: @S.C. You can actually call this in your `render` method right before it returns.

Comment: @DaveSibiski Thanks. Turned out it was **react-native-router** calling `setStyle` here: https://github.com/t4t5/react-native-router/blob/53f74e48bfb06272148d48454ea913d8f62008ff/index.js, so the initial rendering of the app inherits the Status Bar style from there.

Comment: what about for StatusBar? Now StatusBarIOS is deprecated

Comment: @botbot I updated my answer to include information about the new `StatusBar` component. I hope it helps!

Comment: Is it possible to let the text color of the statusbar automatically invert according to the background color?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem. Following docs (https://reactnative.dev/docs/statusbar#barstyle) didn't help.

So, I just did a `Opt+Click` on StatusBar component to found what props you can change, and what methods it provides.

Snippet of props I found:

```
export declare type StatusBarStyle = 'auto' | 'inverted' | 'light' | 'dark';
export declare type StatusBarAnimation = 'none' | 'fade' | 'slide';
export declare type StatusBarProps = {
    /**
     * Sets the color of the status bar text. Default value is "auto" which
     * picks the appropriate value according to the active color scheme, eg:
     * if your app is dark mode, the style will be "light".
     */
    style?: StatusBarStyle;
```

I used this information and updated the StatusBar component like so:

```
<StatusBar style="light" />
```

And voilla, I changed the icons and text color to white!

Answer (score 0):

I had to use `react-native-safe-area-context` and here's how I did it.

```
// ./screens/MyScreen.js
import { StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

const backgroundColor = 'red';

export default () => (
  <View>
    <SafeAreaView edges={['top']} style={{ backgroundColor }}>
      <StatusBar />
    </SafeAreaView>

    <View style={{ backgroundColor }}>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 36 }}>Heading</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

use barStyle="dark-content" ..for example:
`<StatusBar animated={true} backgroundColor="#F1F1F1" barStyle="dark-content" />`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).